# Convert time(7) to bigint T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can I convert `time(7)` type to `bigint` in T-SQL?

I'm trying to update and convert data from column that has `time(7)` data into another column that is a `bigint` type.

Comment: What is the relationship? Do you want the time in seconds since '00:00:00.0000000'? minutes? milliseconds? nanaoseconds? What does the bigint value represent?

Comment: It will represent the timespan's ticks, but initially I want to convert all the data I have as `time(7)` in the database to a `bigint`

Comment: Please try to be bit more clear, show some sample data and expected results.

Comment: What precision is a "tick"?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming when you say "tick" you mean seconds. If you mean milliseconds change "ss" to "ms".

```
Declare @time7 Time(7)
Set     @time7 = Convert(Time(7),Getdate())

Select  Convert(Bigint,Datediff(ss,0,@time7))
```

Comment: You can replace `'00:00:00.0000000'` with `0` in `DateDiff` function. Also a simple note that you are missing the closing bracket of Convert function above.

Comment: No problem!, OP is not very clear about the requirement. +1 for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`datediff` returns an int so if you want the full precision of a time(7) you need to do some calculation. Using `microsecond` or `nanosecond` in `datediff` can result in an overflow.

```
declare @T time(7) = '23:59:58.9999999'
select datediff(second, '00:00', @T) * cast(10000000 as bigint) + right(@T, 7)
```

Result:

```
863989999999
```

It is important to to use `00:00` instead of `0` in the `datediff`. With `0` your time value will be implicitly converted to `datetime` and the value used above will be converted to the value `23:59:59` because the `datetime` is rounded to .000, .003, or .007.

All this would be much easier if [`datediff` supported `bigint`](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/320998/add-datediff-big).